# "git log -- file_name" shows less than "git log --first-parent -- file_name"

Tags: git, git-log

After doing a merge where a file had been deleted, "git log -- file_name" did not show the commit from the current branch. However, the commit shows up if I do "git log" or "git log --first-parent -- file_name". Why?

Steps to recreate:

```
git init
echo "First" > file1.txt
git add file1.txt && git commit -m "Adding file1.txt"
echo "Second" > file2.txt
git add file2.txt && git commit -m "Adding file2.txt"
git checkout -b side_branch
echo "... and third" >> file1.txt  # modifying file1.txt in side_branch
git commit -am "*** Adding third to file1.txt in side_branch"
git checkout master
git rm file1.txt && git commit -m "Removing file1.txt in master"
git checkout side_branch
git merge master
git rm file1.txt && git commit --no-edit

git log -- file1.txt                 # Doesn't show commit with *** 
git log                              # Shows commit with *** 
git log --first-parent -- file1.txt  # Shows commit with *** 
git log --follow -- file1.txt        # Shows commit with ***
```

I thought that that the --first-parent version of the log command would show a subset of the commits listed by the first log command, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the default [History Simplification](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) algorithm realize that the change is made irrelevant by the merge from master. If you turn off the simplification explicitly you get what you expected:

```
git log --full-history -- file1.txt     # Shows commit with ***
```